# How to specify the value for a multiindex in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

Suppose I want to build a pandas dataframe using multiple indexing.

I start defining the expected columns of the dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["val",])
```

Then I build some entries and their indexing:

```
for j in range(1,5):
  tuples = [(str(j), i) for i in range(10)]
  vals = [0,1,2,3,j,j,4,4,1,1]
```

At each iteration of the for loop I would like to update the dataframes with the new values. The method `_append` does not seem to support indexes specification and I've read that the `.loc` method is much more efficient.

So I was trying something like:

```
for i2, el in enumerate(tuples):
  df.loc[el] = vals[i2] #el is a tuple
```

But this is not working as I expected:
If I try to execute the command with a single multi index and a single value, similar to:

```
df.loc[('1', 3)] = 4
```

I get a dataframe that looks like:

```
     val    3
1  NaN  4.0
```

whereas I was expecting something like:

```
      val
1  3  4.0
```

How to specify the value for a multiindex in a pandas dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parentheses in `df.loc[('1', 3)]` don't make it a MultiIndex. In fact it's equivalent to `df.loc['1', 3]`, meaning row `'1'`, column `3`.

You would need to use:

```
df.loc[('1', 3), 'val'] = 4
```

But the Index cannot be altered dynamically.

You must define the MultiIndex from the beginning:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["val",],
                  index=pd.MultiIndex(levels=[[], []], codes=[[], []]))
df.loc[('1', 3), 'val'] = 4
```

Output:

```
    val
1 3   4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems to work. Can I assign multiple rows in one shot, like `df.loc[tuples, "val"] = array_of_values`

Comment: If the indices are pre-existing, yes. Otherwise no and it's inefficient to repeatedly add rows. In this case it's better to collect the values in a list during the loop, then to convert to DataFrame and to `concat` to the original dataframe.